# PhpStorm, Vagrant, Xdebug

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to setup PhpStorm, Vagrant, Xdebug though I've gotten to a point where my application only breaks on index.php. As far as I know I have setup path mappings correctly, and I'm able to programatically trigger the breakpoint with xdebug_break(); Here's a copy of my xdebug.log:

```
Log opened at 2014-08-15 03:53:49
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.56.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2127" idekey="10295"><engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 0 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="0" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- status -i 3
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="3" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="4" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/index.php" lineno="3"></xdebug:message></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///var/www/application/module/html.php -n 7
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="21270029"></response>

<- stack_get -i 6
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="6"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/index.php" lineno="3"></stack></response>

<- run -i 7
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="7" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- run -i 8
Log closed at 2014-08-15 03:53:49
```

Any insights?

I now have two breakpoints, only the first one is firing. Here's my updated xdebug.log:

Log opened at 2014-08-16 13:36:33
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 10.0.2.2:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
->

<- feature_set -i 0 -n show_hidden -v 1
->

<- feature_set -i 1 -n max_depth -v 1
->

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_children -v 100
->

<- status -i 3
->

<- step_into -i 4
->

<- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///var/www/application.php -n 8
->

<- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t line -f file:///var/www/application/module/html.php -n 23
->

<- stack_get -i 7
->

<- run -i 8
->

<- stack_get -i 9
->

<- context_names -i 10 -d 0
->

<- context_get -i 11 -d 0 -c 0
->

<- context_get -i 12 -d 0 -c 1
->

<- run -i 13
->

<- run -i 14
Log closed at 2014-08-16 13:36:37

Here's my PhpStorm log:

2014-08-16 09:34:35,431 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,485 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: PhpStorm (build #PS-133.982, 25 Feb 2014 00:00) 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,485 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 8 (6.2, x86) 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,485 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 1.7.0_40-b43 (Oracle Corporation) 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,485 [     54]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 24.0-b56 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM) 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,487 [     56]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 7.1.3\lib\boot.jar -Didea.platform.prefix=PhpStorm -Didea.no.jre.check=true -Didea.paths.selector=WebIde70 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,552 [    121]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library loaded (32-bit) in 64 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,696 [    265]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Snappy library loaded (1.0.5) in 144 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,698 [    267]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2014-08-16 09:34:35,699 [    268]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Using "FocusKiller" library to prevent focus stealing. 
2014-08-16 09:34:36,553 [   1122]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor intellilang-python-support.xml 
2014-08-16 09:34:36,583 [   1152]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor intellilang-python-support.xml 
2014-08-16 09:34:37,264 [   1833]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - 50 plugins initialized in 1060 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:37,265 [   1834]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: ASP (0.1), Apache config (.htaccess) support (133.982), CSS Support, CVS Integration (11), CoffeeScript (2.0), Command Line Tool Support (133.982), Database Support (1.0), Drupal Support (133.982), File Watchers (999.999), Framework MVC Structure Support (133.982), GNU GetText files support (*.po) (134.SNAPSHOT), Gherkin (1.2), Git Integration (8.1), GitHub, Google App Engine Support for PHP (133.982), HAML, HTML Tools (2.0), IDEA CORE, Ini4Idea (133.982), Inspection-JS (2.0), IntelliLang (8.0), Java Server Pages Integration (1.0), JavaScript Debugger (1.0), JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4), JavaScript Support (1.0), LESS support, PHP (133.982), Perforce Integration (2.0), Phing Support (133.982), QuirksMode, REST Client, ReStructuredText Support (134.SNAPSHOT), Refactor-X (2.01), Remote Hosts Access (0.1), SASS support, SQL support (1.0), SSH Remote Run (0.1), Subversion Integration (1.1), Task Management (1.0), Terminal (0.1), TextMate bundles support (VERSION), Twig Support (133.982), UML Support (1.0), Vagrant (133.982), W3C Validators (2.0), XPathView + XSLT Support (4), XSLT-Debugger (1.4), YAML, hg4idea (10.0) 
2014-08-16 09:34:37,265 [   1834]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: LiveEdit (1.17.133.1) 
2014-08-16 09:34:37,738 [   2307]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=498008064 
2014-08-16 09:34:37,812 [   2381]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm 7.1.3\bin\fsnotifier.exe 
2014-08-16 09:34:37,823 [   2392]   INFO - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Native file watcher is operational. 
2014-08-16 09:34:38,959 [   3528]   INFO - lij.diagnostic.DebugLogManager - Set DEBUG for the following categories: [com.jetbrains.php.debug] 
2014-08-16 09:34:39,202 [   3771]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/macros.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:39,208 [   3777]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/quicklists.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:39,639 [   4208]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/terminal.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:39,682 [   4251]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/textmate.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:39,684 [   4253]   INFO - pl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl - 81 application components initialized in 2383 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:39,731 [   4300]   INFO - .intellij.idea.IdeaApplication - App initialization took 4746 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:39,818 [   4387]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/customization.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:39,855 [   4424]   INFO - om.intellij.util.ProfilingUtil - Profiling agent is not enabled. Add -agentlib:yjpagent to idea.vmoptions if necessary to profile IDEA. 
2014-08-16 09:34:40,052 [   4621]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/applicationLibraries.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:40,531 [   5100]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/plainTextFiles.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:41,033 [   5602]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/deployment.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:41,145 [   5714]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/frameworkRootSettings.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:41,234 [   5803]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 124 project components initialized in 1118 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:41,273 [   5842]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 1 module(s) loaded in 39 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:41,769 [   6338]   INFO - .roots.impl.DirectoryIndexImpl - Directory index initialized in 165 ms, indexed 629 directories 
2014-08-16 09:34:41,775 [   6344]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/sqldialects.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:41,851 [   6420]   INFO - pl.PushedFilePropertiesUpdater - File properties pushed in 78 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,002 [   6571]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/templateLanguages.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,004 [   6573]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/templateLanguages.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,200 [   6769]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,221 [   6790]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/codeStyleSettings.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,223 [   6792]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/projectCodeStyle.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,328 [   6897]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 437 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,328 [   6897]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 0 files to update 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,329 [   6898]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update done in 1 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,548 [   7117]   INFO - ction.BrowserConnectionManager - Browser connected: version 2.0.4, CHROME 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,609 [   7178]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/fileColors.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,782 [   7351]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/IntelliLang.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:42,969 [   7538]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/phing.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:44,073 [   8642]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/watcherTasks.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:44,514 [   9083]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/intentionSettings.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:45,069 [   9638]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/cachedDictionary.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:45,966 [  10535]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/webResources.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:34:46,939 [  11508]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 6869 ms 
2014-08-16 09:34:55,844 [  20413]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/php.xml file is null 
2014-08-16 09:35:10,223 [  34792]  DEBUG - .connection.PhpDebugConnection - 20835709#----connection started 
2014-08-16 09:35:10,262 [  34831]  DEBUG - p.debug.common.PhpDebugProcess - 9449456# Stop at ('file:///var/www/application.php':7) 
2014-08-16 09:35:10,262 [  34831]  DEBUG - p.debug.common.PhpDebugProcess - 9449456# remote: 'file:///var/www/application.php' <-> local: 'C:\Storage\Web Development\Application\application.php' 
2014-08-16 09:35:10,262 [  34831]  DEBUG - p.debug.common.PhpDebugProcess - 9449456# remote: 'file:///var/www/application.php' <-> extracted: '/var/www/application.php' 
2014-08-16 09:35:26,230 [  50799]  DEBUG - .connection.PhpDebugConnection - 20835709#---input stream is finished 
2014-08-16 09:35:26,230 [  50799]  DEBUG - .connection.PhpDebugConnection - 20835709#---stop writing 
2014-08-16 09:35:26,230 [  50799]  DEBUG - .connection.PhpDebugConnection - 20835709#---stop reading 
2014-08-16 09:35:26,230 [  50799]  DEBUG - .connection.PhpDebugConnection - 20835709#----connection stopped

Comment: Not enough info, at all. BTW -- does `xdebug_break();` works fine when placed in your code?

Comment: It does work when I add xdebug_break();

Comment: I do not know then. All what I see from this log is: xdebug itself breaks in `/var/www/index.php`; you trying to set breakpoint in `/var/www/application/module/html.php`. Is 2nd path definitely correct? Any chance that there is any symbolic links in it? If paths are correct -- then maybe it's actual PHP code -- what kind of line that breakpoint is set on? xdebug is not always able to break on certain lines (e.g. multiline statements etc).

Comment: This is the line that it is trying to break on:

$html = $this->document->saveXML($root);

I'm pretty sure that the paths are correct. The virtual host is set to use /var/www as the docroot. The project resides in C:\Storage\Web Development\Application\application. Vagrant is inside that directory and maps it to /var/www.

Comment: Well .. as far as I can tell from the info you have provided: all seems to be OK. Maybe that 2nd file is not get called at all? Other than that -- no other clues. I may only suggest to check what PhpStorm thinks about it -- collect debugging logs and see what you may learn from it: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: I am able to step into the file though.

Comment: Have you set up your path mappings on phpstorm (settings->php->servers->use path mappings so that it knows that /var/www/application/module/html.php is the same file as <projectroot>/application/module/html.php? (you'll need to do that if you have symlinks putting your project into /var/www for example)

Also, if you are on a case sensitive file system, you might have something like an include_once('Html.php') such that the case doesnt actually match, but it works anyhow because you're on ext4 or windows.

Comment: As far as I know autoloading takes into account for this forcing all classes to have a lowercase class name, and the files and folders within the root directory follow this convention as well. The root directory on my windows system however is not lowercase (C:\Storage\Web Development\Application.) Could this be the cause?